# Spring Data Elasticsearch - How to get mapping for a field

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Wondering how to do this in java using spring data elasticsearch library.

```
 GET /my-index-000001/_mapping/field/user
```

Comment: What have you tried ? Where are you stuck ?

Comment: I've tried using IndexOperations.getMapping() and that gives me the mapping for the index. However, I couldn't find a method that gives me the mapping for a specific field of the index, something like IndexOperations.getMapping(String field).

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/IndexOperations.html the doc does not have anything that could do what you are looking for. you will have to do it by hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported by Spring Data Elasticsearch. You'll have to get the mapping for the index and extract the part you need from the returned `Map<String, Object>`.